# Fat finger control when a user double clicks several times on a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have implemented a user following mechanism through JavaScript Embedded Ruby which sends requests asynchronously to the server without leaving the page:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

In the event a user double clicks on the follow button (combined with low server response times), the system sends multiple requests to the server. As a consequence, the current user follows the other user twice and @user.followers.count is increased by +2.

In other words, how can I implement a "Fat finger" control so that my app only sends one request in case the user double clicks several times the follow button?

How can I setup my app in such a way so that, for any button in my app, it gets disabled as soon as it's clicked and re-enabled based on the AJAX's result callback?

Looking forward,
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button as soon it is clicked and re-enable it from your AJAX's result callback.

Comment: Any idea how I can setup my app in such a way so that this control is applied to all the buttons in my app?

Comment: Something like: $('form').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr ('disabled', 'disabled');
});